# Can a relative pronoun give information about words in a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, relative-pronouns

> He was the most prominent of the French artists **who** welcomed
> photography as help-mate but recognized its limitations

Does *who* (relative clause) give information about 'him' or 'French artists' ?

> These writers reflected the opposition of a section of the cultural
> elite in England and France to the cheapening of art **which** the growing acceptance and purchase of camera pictures by the middle class
> represented

Does *which* give information about 'cheapening of art'?

And does **in England and France** modify the *cultural elite* or the *opposition*?

Comment: In general, a PP modifies the thing directly before it, but when that results in an absurd meaning, you backtrack until you find a non-absurd meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *He was the most prominent of the French artists* [*who welcomed*
> *photography as help-mate but recognized its limitations*].
>
> [2] *These writers reflected the opposition of a section of the cultural*
> *elite in England and France to the cheapening of art* [*which the growing*
> *acceptance and purchase of camera pictures by the middle class*
> *represented*].

In [1] the antecedent of "who" is "French artists", a nominal within the NP "the French artists", which is part of the *of* PP.

In [2] the antecedent of "which" is "cheapening of art". The PP "in England and France" modifies "cultural elite".

Notes:

1. Defining relative clauses modify nominals, not NPs, hence the determiner "the" is not part of the antecedent.
2. It's not the relative pronoun that gives information about the antecedent, but the whole relative clause.
3. Since "the most prominent of the French artists ..." in [1] is subjective predicative complement of "be", the content of the relative clause indirectly gives information about the subject "he".

Answer (score 0):

1. The relative clause is within the preposition phrase.
   Delacroix was one [of the French artists who...].

The relative clause is about artists who welcomed photography but recognized its limitations. Delacroix was one of them.

2. Yes, the relative clause that starts with "which the growing..." refers to "the cheapening of art".
3. The phrase "in England and France" refers to "cultural elite".

Comment: Then if the author wanted to give information about 'him' then the sentence would be like 'he was the most prominent of the French artists, who welcomed photography as help-mate but recognized its limitations' ??

Comment: Yes, if the author wanted to say that. Your sentence should not have a comma after "artists", since what follows is a restrictive clause. It is restrictive because you aren't saying the Delacroix was the most prominent of all French artists, just of the ones who did what the clause said.